# how to display a row # when looping through 2 different custom fields

Tags: channel-entries, ee3, grid, vmg-chosen-member

I'm trying to spit out a table with first column being the # of row basically.  However my {count} keeps resetting for each field loop.  I need my count to stay the same

I have a VM Chosen field that I first loop through to display rows of all players in that field.  I use {count} and works fine.  Then I loop through a grid field and list out all players from that but the {count} resets to 1 because it's a new loop.  I have all this wrapped inside a channel entries tag with limit="1" to a specific entry_id.

Can you create a variable and increment it in EE without a plugin?  I've never used Stash but it sounds like that would be a solution?

Comment: If your using grid have u tried `grid:coumt` ?

Comment: ya but that would still start at 1.  I just realized I could probably use PHP to set a variable and increment it I bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes.. Php was the way to go here in the template.  I created a php variable set to 1 and then within each loop I just incremented it and spit out the php variable so it kept a 1-10 list and never reset